# Add step size to a linear optimization

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm working on a blending problem similar to the [pulp example](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html)

I have this constrain to make sure the quantity produced is the desired one

```
prob += lpSum([KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) == 64, "KGRequirement"
```

But I also need to add another constraint for the minimun value different than zero, this is because is not convenient that I take for example, 0.002KG of one ingredient, I have to take either 0 or at least 2 kg, hence valid cases are e.g. 0, 2, 2.3, 6, 3.23.

I tried to make it this way:

```
for i in deposit:
    prob += (KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] == 0) or (TM[i] * deposit_vars[i] >= 30)
```

But that is not working and it just make the problem Infeasible

**EDIT**

This my current code:

```
import pulp
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd

food = ["f1","f2","f3","f4"]
KG = [10,20,50,80]
Protein =       [18,12,16,18]
Grass = [13,14,13,16]
price_per_kg =  [15,11,10,22]

##            protein,carbohydrates,kg

df = pd.DataFrame({"tkid":food,"KG":KG,"Protein":Protein,"Grass":Grass,"value":price_per_kg})


deposit =  df["tkid"].values.tolist()

factor_volumen = 1



costs =  dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(df["tkid"],df["value"]))
Protein =  dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(df["tkid"],df["Protein"]))
Grass =  dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(df["tkid"],df["Grass"]))
KG =  dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(df["tkid"],df["KG"]))

prob = LpProblem("The Whiskas Problem", LpMinimize)
deposit_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",deposit,0)
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]), "Total Cost of Ingredients per can"

#prob += lpSum([deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) == 1.0, "PercentagesSum"
prob += lpSum([Protein[i] *KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) >= 17.2*14, "ProteinRequirement"
prob += lpSum([Grass[i] *KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) >= 12.8*14, "FatRequirement"
prob += lpSum([KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) == 14, "KGRequirement"
prob += lpSum([KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) <= 80, "KGRequirement1"

prob.writeLP("WhiskasModel.lp")
prob.solve()
# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print ("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

# Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
for v in prob.variables():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
print ("Total Cost of Ingredients per can = ", value(prob.objective))
```

The new contrain I want to add is in this part:

```
prob += lpSum([KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] for i in deposit]) <= 80, "KGRequirement1"
```

Where I want the product KG[i] * deposit_vars[i] be either 0 or to be between **a** and **b**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the traditional linear programming formulation, all variables, objective function(s), and constraints need to be continuous. What you are asking is how to make this variable a discrete variable, i.e. it can only accept values a,b,... and not anything in between. When you have a combination of continuous and discrete variables, that is called a mixed integer problem (MIP). [See PuLP documentation that reflects this explanation.](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/optimisation_concepts.html?highlight=linear) I suggest you carefully read the blending problems mentions on "integers;" they are scattered about the page. According to PuLP's documentation, it can solve MIP problems by calling external MIP solver, some of which are already included.

Without a minimum working example, it is a little tricky to explain how to implement this. One way to do this would be to specify the variable(s) as an integer with the values it can take as a dict. Leaving the default solver, [COIN-OR's CBC solver](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) solver, will then solve the MIP. Meanwhile, here's a couple of resources for you to move forward:

- https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/mixed-integer-programming#example-problem-scheduling

  - Note how it uses CBC solver, which is the default solver, to solve this problem
- http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/08/scheduling-easy-mip.html

  - A more explicit example on how they set-up their integer variables and call the CBC solver

Comment: I have edited the question to add the working code I currently have

Comment: See @Erwin's reponse below on the `or` usage.  He is correct, as it makes your constraint non-continuous.  Additionally, `KG[i]*deposit_vars[i]` constraint is now a quadratic constraint, which is a much more difficult problem to solve and perhaps beyond the capabilities of the CBC solver.  You may need a much more sophisticated solver, like Gurobi, which PuLP can interface with. Either way, expect it to take much longer...

Answer (score 2):

'**or**' is not something you can use in an LP / MIP model directly. Remember, an LP/MIP consists of a linear objective and linear constraints.

To model `x=0 or x≥L` you can use socalled **semi-continuous variables**. Most advanced solvers support them. I don't believe Pulp supports this however. As a workaround you can also use a **binary variable** δ:

```
δ*L ≤ x ≤ δ*U
```

where `U` is an upperbound on `x`. It is easy to see this works:

```
δ = 0   ⇒   x = 0
δ = 1   ⇒   L ≤ x ≤ U
```

Semi-continuous variables don't require these constraints. Just tell the solver variable `x` is semi-continuous with bounds [L,U] (or just L if there is no upperbound).

The constraint

```
a*x=0   or   L ≤ a*x ≤ U
```

can be rewritten as

```
δ*L ≤ x*a ≤ δ*U
δ binary variable
```

This is a fairly standard formulation. Semi-continuous variables are often used in finance (portfolio models) to prevent small allocations.

All of this keeps the model perfectly **linear** (not quadratic), so one can use a standard MIP solver and a standard LP/MIP modeling tool such as Pulp.

Comment: Are you sure this workaround is allowed in PulP? The fact that you are multiplying two different variables (δ and L) does not make the problem non-linear?

Comment: @magnum87  L and U are constants.